# Spring Boot: Post Request with JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a controller endpoint that takes `EmployeeRequest` as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "Marry Boython",
    "email": "marry@gmail.com",
    "country": "UK",
    "age": "25"         
}
```

For creating multiple employees, I use a static list in the Application class so that they are populated to the database when running the app. However, I want to create these employees from a json file and sending `List<EmployeeRequest>` to the service.

I tried the following aproach, but not sure where I point the location of my json file. So, is that the right approach that I am looking to read json and send list of the items in it to the service?

```
@PostMapping(
            value = "/createAll", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDto>> createAll(
        @RequestBody List<EmployeeRequest> requests) {
    final List<EmployeeDto> employees = employeeService.create(requests);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(employees);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create json file within your application or it must be passed on to your service externally?

Comment: Do you want to add the employees reading from a json file or do you want to send them as a body? So would the app need to read automatically a json file saved on your machine or would you need to paste the "json file" inside the request body?

Comment: Yes, I have a JSON file having list of the Employees as JSON (multiple of the given single Employee in JSON) and then directly read that json as `List<EmployeeRequest>` of request instead of single `EmployeeRequest`. ANy example Controller method for that?

Comment: @L_Cleo I want to read it directly from a json file in the resources folder. For more detail please see my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok from my understanding you would need no body as request input. Instead, you'd want a controller that takes as input a file name so that you can dynamically load a .json file. Your controller method would look something like this:

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public Controller(ObjectMapper mapper, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}

@PostMapping("/load/{fileName}")
public void loadResource(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    Resource resource =resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:"+fileName);
    log.debug("Found file " + resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    List<Person> people = mapper.readValue(resource.getFile(), new TypeReference<>() {
    });
    log.info(String.valueOf(people));
}
```

Where the `People.class` would be your list of objects that are contained in the json file (EmployeeRequest)

Your .json files would need to be placed with this structure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. What do you think about [these approaches](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) that I just seen while waiting your answer? Which one in these approach should I stick to?

Comment: I would avoid resourceutils, classpath resource and ResourceLoader (the one used in my answer) are basically the same

Comment: If the answer solved your issue please accept the answer so that other people know what to try when facing your same issue

Comment: Then you suggest `ResourceLoader`, is the reason "lazy loading"? Or what is the advantage over other choices? Any clarification pls?

Comment: I am also wondering what is the `fileName` parameter? Can we use it as the name of json file?

Comment: yes, when calling the POST request /load/person.json it will load the person.json file in resources, while calling /load/other.json will load the other.json file

Comment: I thought like that, but I think we need to update `classpath:people.json` as it always open person.json. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, sorry I forgot to use the variable :D fixed it

Comment: Thank you so much. I will mark it as answer, but you missed a question. What is the advantage of using this approach over `ResourceLoader` mentioned on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access#3-using-resourceloader?

Comment: The approach I used IS with ResourceLoader, just made it dynamically load it through and endpoint

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If you already have this JSON file, keep it on **resources** folder. Then read the JSON file. You should write the business logic on **service class** that looking and put files' data into the Database.

**Update implementation:**

If you use **maven** project, update maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now follow the code:

Put this JSON **"Employee.json"**(Any name but update as well) into **resources** folder.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/createAll")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAll() {
        employeeService.create();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Employees Inserted to DB", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    // @Autowired
    // private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    public void create() {
        try {
            File resource = new ClassPathResource("Employee.json").getFile();
            String employeeJson = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<EmployeeDto>>() {}.getType();
            List<EmployeeDto> employees = new Gson().fromJson(employeeJson, listType);
            // Call repository method to save employee list
            // employeeRepository.saveAll(employees);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, the service method is ready and I would also keep json file in the resource folder. But I have no idea how could I show the location in the Controller. Could you post an example Controller endpoint for that?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: @diana I was busy in my office. Please check my updated code. If you have any confusion please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you sent everything except from the one that only need: Controller method. I already have necessary service method, etc.

Comment: @diana, hope you enjoy this code.

Comment: Anyway, voted up for your help even if not helped so much. If you want to help and have time, could you pls clarify me which approach on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access#3-using-resourceloader) page would you suggest for my scenario?

Comment: @diana, use ResourceLoader, If you have large JSON file. It lazily loads resources.

Comment: Why voted down? If you did not, what about vote up to compensate downed voters?